# SEO META Tags - HTML

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

So I might be asking this in the wrong place. I figured since it *technically* does have to do with markup, it might make sense to post it here.

**Issue**

I have my site registered with the three major search engines - Google, Yahoo, and Bing. I have webmaster tools setup for all 3, and frequently check things like traffic, search queries, etc. Recently, I decided to go to Google and just search for some terms related to my site. A bunch of similar sites came up, but not mine. When you search for my site directly, we are the first one - so that's good. So my main issue is, we're no where to be seen when searching terms that *describe* our site, we only have the more "direct" market down.

**Question**

How can I get these search engines to start letting these terms find my site as well? Is this only done by just creating a random META tag on each page on my website, and doing something like this?

```
<META name="keywords" content="location, based, messaging, social, network, service, nearby, friends, community, neighborhood, local, events" />
```

I already have some META tags on my site, but they are the ones to actually set it up and register it with those webmaster tools, I'm assuming I wouldn't do this keyword registration there.

Now, after I set a META tag up like the one I posted above, do I kind of just wait until these search engines register everything? Is this even the best way to do this? Is this even *a* way to do this?

Updated: The meta tag was missing forward slash for closing the tag. It may be the cause the Search engines ignoring the website/page

Comment: I voted to close/migrate this question to [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com). After 5 votes, this will be transferred automatically, so you don't need to re-post this particular question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Search engines started to drop support for the keywords tag in 1998 and finished by 2002!

The only tags that have anything to do with SEO are the title tag and the meta description tag.

Do you have words you want to link to your site on the site?

I'd recommend starting a blog, then using that to write about things you do, that way you definitely have terms that you want to rank for on the page.

Comment: Thanks! However I'm a little confused with the last comment. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, on a normal site, you might not have much text that you want to rank for. A wedding photographer for instance might not list every venue they go to. By having a blog they could post weekly a post explaining what venue they went to, and how they had a "relaxed and contemporary" wedding, or whatever. This will mean their page will now be found on Google when searching for either the venue or the phrase "relaxed and contemporary". Over time they will be found for everything that is useful.

Comment: So does Google also index by what text is on your page? If so, I could just add some key words to a "What Is" section on the site instead of doing all this stuff.

Comment: I believe order of importance for Google is: Text on page, Title of page, Link text to page from other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword META isn't really used by search engines anymore. Too many people where putting irrelavant "search bait" in there.

The new preferred system to use "rich snippets": http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=21997

Comment: I second that rich snippet approach. Having your company adress, customer reviews and products tagged with a microformat understood my google is a benefit!

Comment: Rich snippets don't influence your position though. Just what you look like